# jQuery select all tables with id starting by

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to select all the tables where the id starts with the same sentence, with jQuery.

This what I mean:

```
<table id="Tab_01">
    <tr>
        <td>....
    <tr>
    ....
</table>

<table id="Tab_02">
    <tr>
        <td>....
    <tr>
    ....
</table>
<table id="Tab_03">
    <tr>
        <td>....
    <tr>
    ....
</table>
<table id="xyz">
    <tr>
        <td>....
    <tr>
    ....
</table>
```

What I need, is to select the tables that start with **"Tab_"** and not the table with id = "xyz"

I would like to use this code for making a similar navigation with this plugin :
http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_evtpaginate/demo_basic.html

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you not just add a class to all those tables? That would probably be quicker and easier.

Comment: Adding a class would be better, but this can be done as is. See Ken Redler's answer.

Comment: The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) suggests using this selector in Ken Redler's answer "[...] for identifying elements in pages produced by server-side frameworks that produce HTML with systematic element IDs." rossale might not be able to add classes to the elements.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$('table[id^=Tab_]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Padolsey created a good plugin for this. Check it [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/).

```
$("table:regex(id, ^Tab)")
```

this is the best optimized way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `filter()`:

```
$('table').filter(function(index){
    return this.id.substring(0,4) == 'Tab_';
});
```